# Run specific code when overloading C++ operators

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, overloading

I have a class, let's call it **Foo**, which contains the 3 following methods (overloading the **left-associative** < binary operator):

```
... operator<(A a) { return *this; }
... operator<(B b) { return *this; }
... operator<(C c) { return *this; }
```

A, B, C classes are not related in any way(if that, is of any matter).

Now In my program I only have the 2 following cases:

```
A a = new A();
B b = new B();
C c = new C();

(First Case): new Foo() < a < b;
```

or

```
(Second Case): new Foo() < a < b < c;
```

Whenever I have the first case (which ends with `b`), I want to execute a function run() when I have read(I know) the b instance. So the idea is that I would have the following code in the **Foo** class:

```
... operator<(B b)
{
    run();
}
```

Now when I have the code of the first case, `run()` is being executed.

The problem is that when I have code like in the second case(which ends in `c`).
I want to execute the `run()` function again but NOT until I know what `c` is.
So If I have the previous piece of code `run()` will be called when doing `< b`
which is not what I want as I don't know `c` yet.
If I add `run()` in `operator<(C c)` I will call `run()` twice.

In a few words what I want to accomplish is when having the first case call `run()` at `operator<(B b)` and when I have the second case ONLY call run at `operator<(C c)`.

Any ideas on how this can be solved(if it can)?

Comment: Overriding operators in non standard ways is frowned upon as it is non intuitive to use for the maintainer. Prefer to use methods with a good name that explains what is happening.

Comment: You are mixing the use of objects with pointers. The first step here is to understand the difference and then most of your problems will go away.

Comment: I'm with @Martin on this. You're violating [the basic rules of operator overloading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading/4421708#4421708). Consider using functions instead. Oh, and what you're looking for is expression templates.

Comment: (You should properly @address people in comment replies, so that your replies show up in their "Responses" tab.) No you do not _need_ to do that. I'm certain the way you want to do it will seem _much_ uglier to most seasoned C++ programmers than a solution that involves calling nicely named functions. Abusing operator overloading to make code "neater" basically _always_ fails. Hence the first two basic rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class PreFoo {
public:
    PreFoo() { ... }
    PreFoo & operator<<(A a) { ...; return *this; }
    PreFoo & operator<<(B b) { ...; return *this; }
    PreFoo & operator<<(C c) { ...; return *this; }

    int aa, bb, cc; // save your information
};

PreFoo MakeFoo() { return PreFoo(); }

class Foo {
public:
    Foo(const PreFoo & pre) { run(); } // implicit conversion

    void run() {} // your run!!
};


void g() {
  A a; B b; C c;
  // implicit conversion at the end
  Foo foo1 = MakeFoo() << a << b;
  Foo foo2 = PreFoo() << a << b << c;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could create separate proxy object return types, so when you define an operator for that proxy object, you know which types have gone before it.

Comment: This is way beyond the OP ability level. There are many more fundamental problems that need to be solved first.

Comment: My opinion is: If OP is so unstructured and wrong using instances and pointers then he/she is in the same way unstructured and wrong in it's overall software design.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a syntax tree before, and than evaluate it. So you are creating a DSL, domain specific language.

read this
http://codeidol.com/cpp/cpp-template-metaprogramming/Domain-Specific-Embedded-Languages/-10.5.-Blitz-and-Expression-Templates/

or you can use the boost::proto